# How to sort CoreData string attribute in descending order to find the highest current value?

Tags: objective-c, sorting, ios7, nsarray

I have a CordData store where the primary "key" is a string; I need to sort that key attribute into descending order so I can find the highest current key.  I know I have to convert the key to an int for sorting, but from there I'm lost using comparators (I don't use them often enough to gain any meaningful experience with them).  Here is my code so far (which is wrong, I know):

```
NSArray *sortedArray;
NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sku > %d",0];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
NSArray *skuRecord = [Books MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate];

sortedArray = [skuRecord sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSString *first = [(Books*)a sku];
    NSString *second = [(Books*)b sku];
    return [first compare:second];
}];
```

What's being returned is '1', which is the lowest SKU.  I have looked at SO and Google for hours, and found nothing which would help resolve this problem.  Can someone please tell me what's wrong with my code?  I would appreciate it.

**UPDATE**:  this is the code I finally came up with:

```
NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sku > %d",0];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
NSArray *unsortedArray = [Books MR_findAllWithPredicate: predicate];
int highestSKU = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < unsortedArray.count; i++)  {

    Books *booksManagedObject = (id)unsortedArray[i];  //  now in Books array to be able to access .sku
    NSString *givenSKU = booksManagedObject.sku;
    if([givenSKU intValue] > highestSKU)
        highestSKU = [givenSKU intValue];
}

return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",highestSKU];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual solution to the problem is to [temporarily] pad the character integer values on the left with zeros, which will cause them to sort correctly even as characters (without converting to integers).  Don't know whether this is feasible in your particular instance but I've used that method before.

Comment: Yes, it's feasable, but a PITA... let me try it (I'm getting tired of working on this ONE issue)... I'll respond with points and corrected code if it works.

Comment: Didn't really need to pad them; I just converted to int and did the compare (see my updated question)... thanks tho' you got me on the track to think it out.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort using NSSortDescriptors with strings, no need to convert to integers.

```
NSArray *unsortedArray = @[@"3",@"2",@"5",@"1",@"4"];
NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sorter]];
NSLog(@"First = %@, Last = %@",sortedArray[0],[sortedArray lastObject]);
```

Prints: First = 5, Last = 1

So either I'm missing something in your explanation or vice versa. Did you set ascending to NO?
Your code should look more like this I think;

```
NSArray *unsortedArray = [Books MR_findAllWithPredicate: predicate];
NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sku" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sorter]];
NSLog(@"First = %@, Last = %@",sortedArray[0],[sortedArray lastObject]);
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't do the job... 10 still comes after 9; I want the highest value first.  THis is why the strings have to be converted to int's.

Comment: Still not working; the sort is missing the string '10' as the highest string value... I'm going to try RegularExpression's answer and see if that works any better.

Comment: That's progress anyway.Yeah RegularExpression's technique of padding with leading zero/s should fix that. The sorting algorithm is sorting the strings one character at a time from left to right so 2-9 will be placed after 10 when sorted ascended. In the final version of you app would the sku codes be a fixed length? If so this issue shouldn't be a concern. Also if sku only contain numbers you may be better off storing them as numbers in core data in the first place.